# Multiplying elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Given I have a following list of numbers:

```
l={2,3,4,5,6}
```

I wonder how to multiply each number by the one before of it, 
such that I get

```
{2*3,2*3*4,2*3*4*5,...}
```

Also how can I chose a level for this operation? 
by level I mean,

level 1 : `2*3`

level 2 : `2*3*4`

and so on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
FoldList[Times, l] (* or *)
FoldList[Times]@l
```

> {2, 6, 24, 120, 720}

Also:

```
Exp @ Accumulate @ Log @ l
```

> {2, 6, 24, 120, 720}

Answer (score 4):

```
list = Range[2, 6]

(* {2, 3, 4, 5, 6} *)
```

To keep the factors separate, use [`Inactive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) with kglr's solution

```
list2 = Rest@FoldList[Inactive@Times, list[[1]], Rest@list]
```

[image]

[`Activate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html) produces the result

```
list3 = list2 // Activate

(* {6, 24, 120, 720} *)
```

Or use [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html) to hold the factors

```
list4 = Rest@FoldList[NonCommutativeMultiply, list[[1]], Rest@list]

(* {2 ** 3, 2 ** 3 ** 4, 2 ** 3 ** 4 ** 5, 2 ** 3 ** 4 ** 5 ** 6} *)
```

Then [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) [`Times`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html) to get the final result

```
list5 = Times @@@ list4

(* {6, 24, 120, 720} *)
```

For this specific case (sequential numbers), the result is just [`Factorial`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Factorial.html)

```
list3 == list5 == Factorial /@ Rest@list

(* True *)
```

Use [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) to access any element of the result, e.g.,

```
list3[[1]]

(* 6 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

This can also be solved using recursion. The function cumProd (cumulative product) can be defined as:

```
list = Range[10];
cumProd[n_] := cumProd[n - 1]*list[[n]];
cumProd[1] = list[[1]];
```

To use:

```
cumProd[6]
720
```

gives the 6th "level" of the product. Of course, list can be any set of numbers. Applying this to the whole list:

```
cumProd/@Range[Length[list]]
{1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use the MapIndexed function

```
 list = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
 f[x_, {i_}] := Times @@ list[[1 ;; i]]
 Rest[MapIndexed[f, list, {1}]]
```

(* 6, 24, 120, 720} *)

Answer (score 1):

here is your level function

```
level[x_] := Times @@ l[[;; x + 1]];

level[1]
level[2]
```

> 6
>   24

Comment: Using AbsoluteTiming it would seem that the first answer is the fastest: {4.93665*10^-6, {2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800}} even faster than the built-in function Factorial: {0.0000229201, {6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800}}

Answer (score 1):

**Using `ReplaceList`:**

```
list = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Define:

```
f[k_List] := 
 Riffle[k, "*"] // ToString // 
  StringReplace[#, {"{" -> "", "}" -> "" , "," -> ""}] &

ReplaceList[list
  , {a__, b___} :>
   {f[{a}], Times @@ {a}}
  ] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

This is for mostly useful for presentation purposes.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[1]:=1
f[x_] := f[x] = x f[x-1]

l={2,3,4,5,6}
f/@l

(* {2, 6, 24, 120, 720} *)
```